# Synonym for the tag "adverb-position"

Tags: support, status-completed

Can someone who has earned at least 5 points in questions tagged `adverb-position`, please suggest `adverb-placement` as its synonym. Or nominate the latter to substitute the former, I don't care which. I have tried in vain to do this myself, but apparently I don't have enough rep.... (rolls eyes)

[image: Screenshot of the tag synonym creation page]

There are currently thirty-three questions tagged *[adverb-position](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverb-position.)* but many people ask where *to place* an adverb or about *placement of adverb(s)* as a result many users tag their posts *adverb*, which is too generic. One such case is this question [Placement of adverb relative to verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197809/placement-of-adverb-relative-to-verb)

Comment: Why can't you just use `adverb-position` as a tag in that question?

Comment: @Mitch I could, and I have done in the past but I'm asking about synonym tag. Is that so complicated? Isn't there anybody who has earned five rep points?

Comment: Hi @Mari-LouA - this is weird. You're rep points are in orbit here ... and I think the top end is 20k ... you are over that, so you should be able to do any permissible task here. Is it merely not available as an option for you? If so, this should be brought to the attention of SE.Meta, I'd say.

Comment: @HowardPautz I've posted an image of the message that blocks me from suggesting a synonym.

Comment: My curiosity in the workings of this feature is outweighing my seeing no need at all for such a feature. so I went to http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/adverb-position/topusers, saw that you have 4 pts (as a questioner) and upvoted one of your questions. Hopefully that'll put you over the edge and you can create the synonym now. I checked afterwards and your score still says '4' so maybe it takes a periodic SE utility to update these kinds of scores.

Comment: Well, I properly posted the issue over on se.meta - and got several down votes in a seeming equal number of seconds, revealing two things: there's probably a way of doing this you've not discovered, and, se.meta takes no prisoners ;-P

Comment: @HowardPautz thank you for your interest. I would guess that your question was swiftly downvoted because 1) it was a duplicate, 2) everyone *knows* the rule (5 rep) as it is clearly stated 3) ... depends on the wording of your post. I might query on the necessity of such a rule when a user has accumulated for argument's sake, 15,000 rep.

Comment: @Mitch Nope. I still can't propose a synonym, despite now having 5 points. The situation is absurd, and without any sense. (Thank you for trying to fix it anyways)

Comment: The system for proposing tag synonyms without moderator intervention doesn't really work on sites smaller than Stack Overflow.  Instead, it's best to propose tag synonyms on meta, asking a moderator to create them.

Comment: and as of yet, it doesn't seem like Mari-Lou's original request has been acted on? @snailboat - snail, is there a technical difference that defines 'smaller than' ? I thought all the SE sites were cookie cutter, merely with a different face.

Comment: @HowardPautz, it's pretty simple, actually: all SE sites are smaller than Stack Overflow. :/ SO has several orders of magnitude more questions, answers, and users than most SE sites.

Comment: @Marthaª - seems silly to me that the same code couldn't just be rolled in here. ... oh well :))

Comment: @HowardPautz: the exact same code *is* rolled in here. The problem is with the "exact" part: none of the thresholds have been adjusted for the fact that it's incredibly more difficult to achieve them when you reduce the number of questions, answers, and users by a few factors of ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember seeing this question when it was first posted. I've now created the synonym. However even moderators have to suggest the synonym and then approve their own suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

As snailboat commented, the tag-synonym suggestion system is pretty much unusable. Basically *nobody* has enough reputation to suggest anything, and on the off chance that you find a gap and squeeze in a suggestion, pretty much nobody else will be able to vote on it, even if they manage to find the well-hidden page where the suggestions are listed. Forget about it, and post synonym suggestions as new meta threads instead.